# parsing json api from string array format on android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse the json format:

```
 {"data":["Laptop","Desktop","Ultrabook"]}
```

but this seems to give me an error:

```
 JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

I tried to parse the strings instead, but i doubt thats the best practice.
And, I couldn't figure out how to parse the quotations out of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

to

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Then

```
JSONArray jr = jsonobject.getJSOnArray("data");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
  String value =(String) jr.get(i);
}
```

Your json

```
{ // json object node
    "data": [ // json array data
        "Laptop",
        "Desktop",
        "Ultrabook"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not getting a JSONArray but  JSONObject (the root element is not an array). Try this:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONArray("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

do :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

JSONArray arr =  obj.getJSONArray("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

your first tag in JSONObject not a JSONArray.

So you need to change this from

```
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

to

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
    String data = "{\"data\":[\"Laptop\",\"Desktop\",\"Ultrabook\"]}";

    try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray= jObj.optJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            System.out.println(jsonArray.get(i).toString());

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```